# regex: retrive the lines before the first occurrence of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose that I have the multiline text:

> alpha
>
> beta
>
> gamma
>
> delta

and I want to retrieve only the lines before the first occurrence of `elt` using JS `exec` function, that is:

> alpha
>
> beta
>
> gamma

I've tried with

```
/([\S\s]*)[^\n]*?elt.*/.exec(text)[1]
```

but it returns:

> alpha
>
> beta
>
> gamma
>
> d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for `/([\S\s]*)\n.*?elt/`?

```
var text = "alpha\nbeta\ngamma\ndelta";
console.log(/([\S\s]*)\n.*?elt/.exec(text)[1]);
```

Which gives:

> "alpha
>   beta
>   gamma"

Answer (score 1):

This results in "gamma":

```
var data = "alpha\nbeta\ngamma\ndelta";
var parts = data.match( /.*\n(.*)\n.*elta/m );
console.log(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution ?

```
var s = 'alpha\nbeta\ngamma';
s.split(/\n.*?amm/)[0].split('\n'); // ["alpha", "beta"]

var s = 'alpha\nbeta\ngamma\ndelta';
s.split(/\n.*?amm/)[0].split('\n'); // ["alpha", "beta"]

var s = 'alpha\nbeta\ngama\ndelta';
s.split(/\n.*?amm/)[0].split('\n'); // ["alpha", "beta", "gama", "delta"]
```